# How to use python to convert a float number to fixed point with predefined number of bits

Tags: python, fixed-point, quantization

I have float 32 numbers (let's say positive numbers) in numpy format. I want to convert them to fixed point numbers with predefined number of bits to reduce precision.

For example, number 3.1415926 becomes 3.25 in matlab by using function num2fixpt.
The command is num2fixpt(3.1415926,sfix(5),2^(1 + 2-5), 'Nearest','on') which says 3 bits for integer part, 2 bits for fractional part.

Can I do the same thing using Python

Comment: What's your end goal here?

Comment: i don't want the number to be too precise. For example, to simulate the case using fixed point Digital Signal Processor. I want the float number to be saved in fixed point format with less precision.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it if you understand how IEEE floating point notation works.  Basically you'll need to convert to a python LONG, do bitwise operators, then covert back.  For example:

```
import time,struct,math
long2bits = lambda L: ("".join([str(int(1 << i & L > 0)) for i in range(64)]))[::-1]
double2long = lambda d: struct.unpack("Q",struct.pack("d",d))[0]
double2bits = lambda d: long2bits(double2long(d))
long2double = lambda L: struct.unpack('d',struct.pack('Q',L))[0]
bits2double = lambda b: long2double(bits2long(b))
bits2long=lambda z:sum([bool(z[i] == '1')*2**(len(z)-i-1) for i in range(len(z))[::-1]])

>>> pi = 3.1415926
>>> double2bits(pi)
'0100000000001001001000011111101101001101000100101101100001001010'
>>> bits2long('1111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
18446462598732840960L
>>> double2long(pi)
4614256656431372362
>>> long2double(double2long(pi) & 18446462598732840960L)
3.125
>>>

def rshift(x,n=1):
    while n > 0:
        x = 9223372036854775808L | (x >> 1)
        n -= 1
    return x

>>> L = bits2long('1'*12 + '0'*52)
>>> L
18442240474082181120L
>>> long2double(rshift(L,0) & double2long(pi))
2.0
>>> long2double(rshift(L,1) & double2long(pi))
3.0
>>> long2double(rshift(L,4) & double2long(pi))
3.125
>>> long2double(rshift(L,7) & double2long(pi))
3.140625
```

This will only truncate the number of bits though, not round them.  The rshift function is necessary because python's right-shift operator fills the empty leftmost bit with a zero.  See a discription of IEEE floating point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 2):

You can use **fxpmath** module to work with fractional fixed-point in python.

Module repository: https://github.com/francof2a/fxpmath

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

pi_fxp = Fxp(None, signed=False, n_word=5, n_frac=2)    # create fixed-point object (3 bit for intefer, 2 for fractional)
pi_fxp.rounding = 'around'                              # define rounding method, default is `trunc`.
pi_fxp(3.1415926)                                       # set value

print(pi_fxp)                                           # printed value = 3.25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can round to binary fixed precision without explicit type conversions that tend to generate a lot of interpreter overhead:

```
import numpy as np

n_bits = 2
f = (1 << n_bits)

a = np.linspace(1, 2, 11)
a_fix = np.round(a*f)*(1.0/f)

print a
print a_fix
```

Results in

```
[ 1.   1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2. ]
[ 1.    1.    1.25  1.25  1.5   1.5   1.5   1.75  1.75  2.    2.  ]
```

The example uses numpy, but that's just for the convenience of generating a list of example values. Python's built-in `round` will work just as well for single values:

```
x=3.1415926
x_fix = round(x*f)/float(f)
print x_fix
```

Note that both f and 1.0/f have an exact floating-point representation; therefore, the multiplication and division are exact, without rounding errors. Also note that multiplying by `1.0/f` is about 3x faster than dividing directly in the case of large arrays.

This approach doesn't control the number of bits for the integer part, so if you want the numbers to be capped or wrap around if they are too big, you'd have to do a bit more bit-shifting.

Answer (score 0):

[numfi](https://numfi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a python library that mimic matlab's `fi` fixed point object, it's more like `fixdt` in simulink, but you can change `num2fixpt` to `numfi` by define word/fraction length instead of scaling

```
>>> from numfi import numfi
>>> x = numfi(3.1415926,1,5,2) # 5 word length = 2 fraction + 2 integer + 1 signed
>>> x
numfi([3.25]) s5/2-r/s
```